# Proper way to layout custom pages/modules in Magento

Tags: php, ajax, magento

I'm working for a computer components store.

My end goal is to make a 'Build your own computer' page where customers can pick components from each category (CPU, Memory, etc) and add them all to the cart.

I began by making a custom template file and just making it on a CMS page, but I've hit the point where items need to be added to carts etc, and I was planning on making another php page to add the item to the cart, and access it by AJAX, and I'm starting to get a bit flustered with what I'm making (I'll admit I'm out of my league, but I'm a programming student and am trying to learn.)

How should I be tackling this? Is it wrong to be making such a thing in template files alone? I have an extremely rough understanding of how modules work, but as far as I could tell, you can't have a CMS page with modules on them.

Answer (score 1):

I worked with Magento for a summer and it was quite intimidating and bulky so don't get too discouraged.  As for just working in template files, you will probably need to dig deeper and create your own module at some point which is quite involved.  I'm not sure if you have experience with the MVC (Model View Controller) method of programming but you will need to understand it before you dig into Magento.

I haven't worked with Magento in a while but I'll pass on some resources that helped me and hopefully can help guide you.

Hello World Modules in Magento:  1. http://magento4u.wordpress.com/2009/06/08/create-new-module-helloworld-in-magento/
2. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/basics-creating-magento-module/

Alan Storm has great Magento Tutorials:
http://alanstorm.com/category/magento

Hopefully this is helpful.